# Using an nsimage as a "green screen"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, filter, nsimage

Is it possible for me to take use an image as a green screen type thing like in photo booth where it takes the background out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although exactly what you mean by “green screen” will affect the specific answer. Chroma-keying will require a custom CIFilter, as I don't believe Core Image comes with such a filter and I know NSImage by itself doesn't support it.

Comment: Well I don't necessarily mean nsimage, i don't care by what means it is. I mean that I can take an image, add an image on top of it, and then take the first image out so I only get the image that was added on top of it.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to dig into Core Animation and such.

Comment: Not Core Animation, but Core Image. Unless you mean you just want to completely replace the previous image with the new image; if so, you can do that with NSImage and the `NSCompositeCopy` compositing operator. But that doesn't sound like what you described in your question.